# Group Policy Users Transfer to another PC

Tags: active-directory, user-controls, group-policy

I am currently trying to get some group policies transferred to another PC. The group policies only apply to a single local user. I am trying to transfer the group policies out of the Group Policy User folder onto another PC. The local user has the same name but different SID.

I have tried a few things but nothing worked so far.

To get it to work I have to go into MMC and start the group policies for the local user so the folder is created as a hidden folder. I then can go into the folder it made and replace the contents and it seems to work like this, but not copying just the Group Policy User folder.

Answer (score 0):

First try to force update the Group Policy services, copy-paste this command in Command Prompt window, and hit Enter or try with other method provided below.

```
gpupdate /force
```

Upon the completion of force adaptation of Group Policy, this message will appear-
Updating Policy…The User Policy update has completed successfully. The computer Policy update has completed successfully.
Restart your computer to save the changes on your computer

Another way you can approch because method you are trying is not so much adequate.

Just copying the Local Group policy from one location to another is not adequate. The Security, and Audit permissions are not carried over.

Refer this document to copy the security configuration and audit policy along with group policy object: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/108867-transfer-all-group-policy-settings-from-one-system-to-another

Another way is using installing **LocalGPO** :    http://woshub.com/backupimport-local-group-policy-settings/